# systemd prepending /bin to Environment PATH

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to setup  my Bamboo agents as a systemd service. The service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Atlassian Bamboo Agent
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=bamboo
Group=bamboo
ExecStart=/opt/bamboo-1/bin/bamboo-agent.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/bamboo-1/bin/bamboo-agent.sh stop
Environment="PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I check the process environment, the PATH is correctly set to what I expect, with with the only exception that my PATH is prepended with `/bin`.

```
cat /proc/12345/environ <--- 12345 is my Bamboo PID
...
PATH=/bin:/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
...
```

That means my builds will use the wrong `gcc`, `cmake`, etc.

Is there any way to prevent `/bin` to be prepended to the PATH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a test service that just printed out the path after setting `Environment=` with a new path, and found it worked as expected on Ubuntu 16.04 with systemd 229.

I conclude that something in your script is pre-pending /bin to your environment.

Nothing in the `systemd.exec` man page suggests that systemd is designed to behave the way you observe.

Comment: You are right: Bamboo startup script was adding a `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the `PATH`. Since `JAVA_HOME` was not set, it was actually appending `/bin`. So I resolved this by adding to the service config the proper `Environment` line to set `JAVA_HOME`.