# Running forever index.js from a systemd unit file

Tags: node.js, debian, beagleboneblack, forever, forever-monitor

Beaglebone Debian 8.7;
Node v10.10.0

https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/running-your-node-js-application-on-ecs-with-systemd-or-forever_594909

Attempting to run .js file forever as discussed in the above link. This is the contents of my .service unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=myServer
DefaultDependencies=no
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/forever  start  path/index.js
ExecStop=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin/forever  stop  path/index.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With command *# systemctl start myServer.service* I get the following errors.

```
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
myServer.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

**However** with the command *forever start path/index.js*; everything works fine.

Forever-monitor is installed. Why doesn't my service work compared to a console command.

Comment: Probably you have another `node` version installed in `/usr/local/bin/node` which is normally shadowed in `PATH` by the one provided by `nvm`. Try adding the correct path (`/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin`). You can either do that with an `Environment=` directive but [then you have to specify the whole `PATH`, you can't prepend to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439123/), or use something like `/bin/bash --login -c 'forever start path/index.js'` or possibly `/bin/bash -c 'PATH=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/bin:$PATH forever start path/index.js'`.